# How do I extend memory for my Dynamically allocated storage in "VirtualBox" of Type - "VMDK"

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, centos7, rhel

I am quite new to the VM related configurations. I tried searching Internet for this and found most of the places where having examples for VDI type of storage and couldnt find a good solution for VMDK type of storage.

Also my current disk is Dynamically allocated storage.
[image]

My setup is to run the VirtualBox from my Windows machine to have Linux machine in VM's

Answer (score 0):

vmdk is the originally VMWare file format. May be VirtualBox just doesn't know how to do this :)

You can download free VMware Workstation Player and expand your vitrual disk there.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOz4o.png)